# JQuery: How to access a specific text input of multiple inputs with same ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm havin troubles accessing to the inputs id to do operations, i have this:

```
<input id="id_cot" name="id_cot" type="hidden" value="1">
<input id="id_cot" name="id_cot" type="hidden" value="2">
<input id="id_cot" name="id_cot" type="hidden" value="3">
<input id="id_cot" name="id_cot" type="hidden" value="4">
```

It's generated by my BD, how i can access for example to value 4 via JQuery? Thank u so much

Comment: `ID should always Be unqiue` use class instead

Comment: __Identifiers must be unique__

Comment: `$('input[value=4]')` gets all the element with value = 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Identifiers must be unique*, Using duplicate Id renders your HTML invalid, So you should not it.

However a common class or Attribute value selector (as provided in snippet) can be used.

```js
var arr = $('input[name=id_cot]').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="id_cot" type="hidden" value="1">
<input name="id_cot" type="hidden" value="2">
<input name="id_cot" type="hidden" value="3">
<input name="id_cot" type="hidden" value="4">
```

Comment: Idk what's the problem is with asking something so simple, some people was ofended with this question and they took me away points, this is a learn space and i'm thankful for ur answer and this will be useful for new people in JQuery.. thank u so much

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is: Don't do that. `id` values must be unique in the document. If you use the same `id` on multiple elements, browsers are free to do what they like. (They usually leave the `id` on the elements but if you look for one by ID, they give you the first. But they don't have to do that, so I don't rely on it.)

Since they also have names, you could use the selector `input[name=id_cot]` to get a jQuery set containing all of thos elements, and loop through it (or use `eq` to choose one of them):

```
var inputs = $("input[name=id_cot]");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.id_cot').each(function(i,v){


console.log("Item in index " + i + " has value " + $(v).val())



})

//to get value at index 4..
console.log("Item in input 4 has value " + $('.id_cot').eq(3).val())// get the element at index 3 to get the value 4 use 3 because index starts with 0
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id_cot" name="id_cot" class="id_cot" type="hidden" value="1">
<input id="id_cot" name="id_cot" class="id_cot" type="hidden" value="2">
<input id="id_cot" name="id_cot" class="id_cot" type="hidden" value="3">
<input id="id_cot" name="id_cot" class="id_cot" type="hidden" value="4">
```

Use class with index to get what input you want to get

Answer (score 0):

If you do `$('#id')`, you will get only one element. You can do

```
$('[id=id_cot]')
```

Do get all the elements of the specific id. Then you can access to element #4, by doing:

```
$('[id=id_cot]').eq(3).val() // Your value
```

**Note:** It is really not recommended to use the same ID more than once.

**More Info:**

- [Using the same ID Twice](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/536d26709c4e9d17380002d1)
- [jQuery attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)